# Issue managing to use IntersectionObserver on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener, intersection-observer

As I want to implement animations when each div appears on the screen, I'm using the IntersectionObserver API to know when they're in the viewport.

My idea is to create an observer for each div as follows

```js
this.box.forEach(name => {
  let isVis = false;
  handleEachCategory(name, isVis);
})
```

My data contains the name of the CSS divs and so far I do manage to supposedly create separate observers for each, yet only one of the divs triggers the change of value of isVis (defines when my div is entirely visible.

```js
function handleEachCategory(category, isVis) {
            let target;
            let observer;
            window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
                target = document.querySelector(category);
                createObserver();
            }, false);
            function createObserver() {
                let options = {
                root: null,
                rootMargin: '0px',
                threshold: 1.0
                }
                observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
                observer.observe(target)
            }
            function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1)
                        setAsVisible();
                });
            }
            function setAsVisible() {
                isVis = true;
                console.log(isVis)
            }
        }
```

I am as you can guess, quite new to javascript and my logic is probably failing somewhere, I just can't seem to see how to make it work so far.

Another way to phrase my question would be "how to implement multiple intersection observers", if there is a more standard/preferred way, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code a little, as shown below, which should help you do what you want.
The likely problem with your code was that [window.addEventListener("load"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) only happens once when the page has fully loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  ["one", "two", "three"].forEach(name => {
    handleEachCategory(name);
  });
}, false);



function handleEachCategory(category) {
  let target = document.getElementById(category);
  let observer;
  let isVis;
  createObserver();

  function createObserver() {
    let options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 1.0
    }
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
    observer.observe(target)
  }

  function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1)
        setAsVisible();
    });
  }

  function setAsVisible() {
    isVis = true;
    console.log(`${category} is${(!isVis ? " not" : "")} visible`)
  }
}
```

```css
#one,#two,#three {
min-height: 100px;
}

#one {
background: red;

}

#two {
background: yellow;
}

#three {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="two"></div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works indeed ! That being said I'm confused, you said that my addEventListener only happened once, I thought this was the point of an event listener, once you add it it ... well... listens until you remove or destroy it.

Comment: Yes, it listens for when the page has loaded and loads only once, therefore in your case, if the page loads before handleEachCategory gets called then createObserver will never get called.

Comment: ahahahahahahahahah, okay that makes perfect sense and I only feel 87% stupid.
Thanks again and have a good day :)